# msal-angular for single sign on

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am using msal-angular for multiple Angular 7 applications' authentication. Mostly it is working fine. The only annoying issue is that whenever I switch from one application to another for the first time in browser, it pops up to ask me to "Pick an account". It doesn't automatically use the already signed in account. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When a user authenticates, a **session cookie** is set on the Azure AD domain in the browser. MSAL.js relies on this session cookie to provide [SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso) for the user between different applications. MSAL.js also caches the ID tokens and access tokens of the user in the browser storage per application domain.

You can use **session id(SID)** or **login hint** to automatically select account on Azure AD. Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso#automatically-select-account-on-azure-ad) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I saw this document before, but I don't know how to use it with msal-angular package directly. I will take a further look.